# Custom action on page edit

Tags: custom-action

I have a problem with my custom action. Below is declaration of the custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="CommandUI.Ribbon.List.Text" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm" RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x01">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Embed.Controls._children">

      <Button Id="ITlist.SetText" 
              Sequence="5"
              Command="ITlist.SetText" 
              Image16by16="Images\formatmap32x32.png" 
              Image32by32="Images\formatmap32x32.png"
              LabelText="Add body text" 
              ToolTipTitle="Out-of-box excuse" 
              ToolTipDescription="Help text" 
              TemplateAlias="o1"/>

    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>

  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="ITlist.SetText" 
                      EnabledScript=""  
                      CommandAction="javascript:alert('Test');">
    </CommandUIHandler>
  </CommandUIHandlers>

</CommandUIExtension>
```

The problem is that the custom action button is not visible on a page when it is in edit mode, it is only visible when I'm in edit properties mode of the page.
Can anyone help me to point out where I made mistake??

Answer (score 1):

Use `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"` instead of `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.EditForm"`.